# Unable to see the code line throwing an exception

Tags: c++, c++14

When I compile my code using `g++` with optimisation level `o3` and then debug it using `lldb` until the crash occurs there’s no code line that throws an exception in the back trace. I don't want to use `-g` flag because my source code doesn't have to be visible in production.

Let's consider a simple case:

**test.cpp**

```
int main() {
    bool isOdd = std::rand() & 1;
    if (isOdd) {
        throw std::logic_error("An exception for the odd number was thrown!");
    } else {
        throw std::logic_error("An exception for the even number was thrown!");
    }
}
```

Then I compile it

```
 g++ -o3 -std=c++14 -o test.o test.cpp
```

And view the back trace with the following set of commands:

```
lldb test.o
r
bt
```

But the back trace is not really helpful as it doesn't contain the code line throwing the exception or a string message that is passed to `logic_error` (`"An exception for the odd number was thrown!"` or `"An exception for the even number was thrown!"`):

```
...
frame #7: 0x00007fff5011f26f libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_throw + 121
frame #8: 0x0000000100000e11 test.o`main + 113
frame #9: 0x00007fff5215d015 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
...
```

Is there a way to overcome this limitation without using any external libraries?

I'm using `MacOS` and `g++` as a compiler and `LLDB` as a debugging tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use a variadic template function that re-throws the given exception. Template arguments include `id` and exception arguments. `id` is a unique number that will be used for identifying a line of code on which the exception is thrown. Arguments are used for creating and re-throwing the exception. So, the code could be as follows:

```
template<uint32_t id, class... Arguments>
void rethrow(Arguments&&... args) {
    std::rethrow_exception(std::make_exception_ptr(std::logic_error(std::forward<Arguments>(args)...)));
}

int main() {
    bool isOdd = std::rand() & 1;
    if (isOdd) {
        rethrow<1>("An exception for the odd numbers!");
    } else {
        rethrow<2>("An exception for the even numbers!");
    }
}
```

After I recompiled the code and checked the back trace then in my case `id = 1`:

```
frame #9: 0x0000000100000c65 test.o`void rethrow<1u, char const (&) [34]>(char const (&&&) [34]) + 69
```

So, an exception was thrown from

```
rethrow<1>("An exception for the odd numbers!");
```